# Xamarin Visual Studio Android Setting up A SQLITE DATABASE

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a hard time getting the basics, so apologies if this is simple. I have found no helpful tutorials that work after hours of searching and have given up.

I have gotten to the step where I have downloaded a SQLite.cs file. Now I have no Idea what to do with it. I've followed this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarinforms-and-sqlite--cms-23020 , but I feel like this is outdated or I am doing something seriously wrong. All I'm doing is copy and pasting his code into new classes. It doesn't exactly show the solution explorer so I am sure if anything that is where I am messing up if I have chosen a wrong file type or put code in a wrong file.

I want to just get to a point where I can experiment with simple **crud** with sqlite but I am getting nowhere.

My experience with sql and android development is both beginner. Though queries themselves I'm probably intermediate. Though I always have trouble setting up sql on projects. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Going through this 5 part tutorial should give you a pretty basic idea about how SQLite works in Xamarin.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_1_introduction/

Here's a simple recipe for Android that covers this as well:

https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/android/data/databases/sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use SQLite with Xamarin, is to utilize the official SQLite.NET Xamarin Component, which is offered on the [component site](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net)

The syntax from that point is very .NET friendly. For example, to create/connect to a database, you would do:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var conn = new SQLiteConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "stocks.db"));
conn.CreateTable<Stock>();
conn.CreateTable<Valuation>();
```

From there, adding/deleting/inserting data is also straightforward, take the following code snippet as an example

```
public static void AddStock (SQLiteConnection db, string symbol) {
    var s = new Stock { Symbol = symbol };
    db.Insert (s);
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} == {1}", s.Symbol, s.Id);
}
```

The sample code I have provided is available on the linked site above, as well as in the sample code that is included with the component once it is added to the project.

Thanks!